# Powershell script to get the list of Azure PaaS services

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to get a list of these PaaS services in some subscriptions:

**Azure PAAS Resource**

- SQL Database
- Key Vault
- Application Gateway
- Load Balancers
- Network Interface
- Queue Storage
- File Storage
- Storage Account
- Table Storage
- Apimanagement
- Automation Account
- Data Factory
- Logic Apps
- Recovery Services
- Application Insights
- Cosmos DB
- Machine Learning Workspaces
- Log Analytics

I wrote this script that gets all these services based on the resource type.

```
# Define the PaaS types
$paasTypes = @(
    "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
    "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
    "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
    "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
    "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
    "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
    "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices",
    "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices",
    "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices",
    "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices",
    "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service",
    "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
    "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
    "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults",
    "Microsoft.Insights/components",
    "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
    "Microsoft.MachineLearning/workspaces",
    "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces"
)

# Set your subscription names
$subscriptionIds = @(
    "xxxxxxxx1",
    "xxxxxxxx2",
    "xxxxxxxx3",
    "xxxxxxxx4",
    "xxxxxxxx5"
)

# Output CSV file path
$outputFilePath = "C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXX\PaaSCount.csv"

# Initialize an array to store the results
$results = @()

# Iterate over subscriptions
foreach ($subscriptionId in $subscriptionIds) {
    az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

    $subscriptionName = az account show --query "name" -o tsv

    # Iterate over PaaS types
    foreach ($paasType in $paasTypes) {
        $resources = Get-AzResource -ResourceType $paasType -ExpandProperties

        # Iterate over resources
        foreach ($resource in $resources) {
            # Check if the resource has the specified tag
            if ($resource.Tags['ApplicationName'] -like "*PROD*") {
                $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Subscription = $subscriptionName
                    ResourceGroup = $resource.ResourceGroupName
                    Resource = $paasType
                    Region = $resource.Location
                    ResourceName = $resource.Name
                }

                $results += $result
            }
        }
    }
}

# Export the results to a CSV file
$results | Export-Csv -Path $outputFilePath -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host "CSV file exported to: $outputFilePath"
```

The problem is that the script doesnt output the list of these services:

- Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases
- Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers
- Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices
- Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices
- Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices
- Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices
- Microsoft.ApiManagement/service
- Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts
- Microsoft.DataFactory/factories Microsoft.Logic/workflows
- Microsoft.Insights/components Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts
- Microsoft.MachineLearning/workspaces

Any Help please?

Answer (score 2):

> Powershell script to get the list of Azure PaaS services

Here is the updated `PowerShell` script to fetch the **Azure PaaS** services.

```
    # Define the PaaS types
    $paasTypes = @(
        "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
        "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
        "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
        "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
        "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
        "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service",
        "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts",
        "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
        "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
        "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults",
        "Microsoft.Insights/components",
        "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
        "Microsoft.MachineLearning/workspaces",
        "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces"
    )
    
    # Set your subscription names
   $subscriptionIds = @(
    "xxxxxxxx1",
    "xxxxxxxx2",
    "xxxxxxxx3",
    "xxxxxxxx4",
    "xxxxxxxx5"
)   
    # Output CSV file path
    $outputFilePath = "C:\PowerShell\PaaSCount.csv"
    
    # Initialize an array to store the results
    $results = @()
    
    # Iterate over subscriptions
    foreach ($subscriptionId in $subscriptionIds) {
        $subscription = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
        $subscriptionName = $subscription.Name
    
        # Iterate over PaaS types
        foreach ($paasType in $paasTypes) {
            # Filter resources based on resource type
            $resources = Get-AzResource | Where-Object { $_.ResourceType -eq $paasType }
    
            # Iterate over resources
            foreach ($resource in $resources) {
                # Check if the resource has the specified tag
                foreach ($tagKey in $resource.Tags.Keys) {
                    if ($tagKey -eq 'ApplicationName' -and $resource.Tags[$tagKey] -like "*PROD*") {
                        $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
                            Subscription = $subscriptionName
                            ResourceGroup = $resource.ResourceGroupName
                            Resource = $paasType
                            Region = $resource.Location
                            ResourceName = $resource.Name
                            TagName = $tagKey
                            TagValue = $resource.Tags[$tagKey]
                        }
    
                        $results += $result
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    # Export the results to a CSV file
    $results | Export-Csv -Path $outputFilePath -NoTypeInformation
    
    Write-Host "CSV file exported to: $outputFilePath"
```

**Output:**

[image]

The resource details, including the **resource type**, are exported to an **Excel** file.

[image]

Since the below resource types do not have any tags and are part of the **Storage account**, only the storage accounts will be displayed.

> - Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices
> - Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices
> - Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices
> - Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices